# Images not being served on Heroku Rails 5 App

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

I'm having issues serving static files from my Asset pipeline using Rails 5 on Heroku. I have looked at other questions but none seem to resolve the issue.

I get 
        HomeController#index is missing a template for this request format 
        and variant. request.formats: ["image/png"] request.variant: []

my config/production.rb

```
    config.assets.compile = false

    config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

    if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
     logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
     logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
     config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
    end
```

Comment: The error message `missing a template...` tells you that Rails finds a matching route but it leads to a controller method. Therefore your issue might be related to your `routes.rb` or naming of the files. Where are the missing files locates (in `public` or `app/assets`)? How do you link the files in the views? How does the generated path in the rendered HTML look like? How does your `config/routes.rb` look like? Is `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` actually set on Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile all assets locally and push to heroku.

Try following steps:

1. change line in config/environments/production.rb
   `config.assets.compile = true`
2. Run commands:

   `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`
3. push all compile assets with manifest.rb to `heroku`.

Comment: Compiled assets and artifacts should not be in version control.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling assets locally is not a good practice and should be avoided as artifacts should not be in version control. I was having the same issue while attempting to set a background image using **sass** and using the `image-url` helper generates the correct url.

`background: image-url('my-image.png') no-repeat center;`

For image tags and erb css templates there is the `image_path` and `image_tag` rails helpers.